# Putting a toolbar directly under a navigation controller without hiding the content underneath the toolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to put a toolbar directly beneath a navigation bar but I need the toolbar to not hide the content from the view directly beneath it. My quick solution was to set the navigation controller's native toolbar to visible, which works and properly resizes the view beneath it so that it doesn't let anything hide behind it, BUT the default toolbar shows at the bottom of the screen.

I need it to be at the top, just under the nav bar. I figure the easy solution would be to change the frame of the default toolbar (which I don't know how to do) OR to position a new instance of the toolbar onto the view (which works but it hides the content beneath it) but have it resize the views below.

Please see the following image that I found to see what I'm trying to do. (note how the tableview's first row starts UNDER the tab bar)

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: When trying to do this type of feature, its really useful to take the current view and walk the superview, print out their frames. You will then be able to better assess what action to take. If you want to say animate this toolbar from under the Navigation bar, the toolbar will have to be inserted in a view at the same or lower in the hierarchy. Keep in mind you can set the frame of something to have an origin that has a negative y, then when you animate you change the y to a more positive value. In the end you can do what you want but it might take some investigative effort on your side.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things.  The NavigationController toolbar property IS the bottom bar, any toolbar that you add to a view has nothing to do with the nav controller but is a property of that view.

If you have your own toolbar at the top of a view you need to move the rest of the view content down or set that toolbar to translucent if thats what your looking for.

Again the nav controller toolbar is always the bottom bar, the toolbar you drop in IB is just a toolbar for that view that you can put anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change the frame of the default toolbar. You will need to create your own instance of a toolbar, position it at the bottom of the navigation bar and resize your tableView to fit below.
We can't see how you have your views set up but if you are starting with a view that is subclassed as UITableViewController you will have trouble doing that. What you want is to start with a UIViewController as your master controller, add a tableview and toolbar as subviews. Then position and size them as appropriate.

If you are hiding and showing the toolbar you will create a method to move it up under the navigation controller and again resize the tableview.